# How to Permanently change PowerShell and CMD prompts

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

`PowerShell` prompt can be changed by calling

```
Function prompt{"new_prompt "}
```

and on the `cmd` prompt can be changed by calling

```
prompt $g$g$s
```

Once the current window is closed all the changes are gone and one will have to change them again when opening new instances of `PowerShell` or `cmd`. How can one make these changes permanent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For PowerShell you'd put your custom `Prompt()` function in the relevant [profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx).

```
function Prompt {
    "PS ${env:USERNAME}@${env:COMPUTERNAME} $(Get-Location)> "
}
```

For CMD you'd set/modify the PROMPT environment variable, e.g. via [`setx`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc755104.aspx):

```
setx PROMPT "%"USERNAME"%"@"%"COMPUTERNAME"%"$s$m$p$g$s
```

Answer (score 3):

You have profile where you can put initialization for your PowerShell command prompts.

Type `$profile` in your PowerShell command to see where it resides

Then modify it or create a new one if there doesn't exist one e.g. profile.ps1.

e.g. then add

```
function prompt { "PS " + $(get-date) ">"}
```

You can read more about profiles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-use-profiles-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Note that the string value of `$profile` default to the profile path for the current user and and the current host, to see all currently applicable profiles for a session do `$profile|select *`