# Changing input cursor in command line of terminal

Tags: python, terminal, formatting

New to Python. How do you change the input cursor / bullet point in the command line in the terminal from the path of the file to a simple '>' ? Picture attached:)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc7xe.png)

I have dug around in the settings and tried to google but it is proving tricky to find.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, you need to run `function prompt {"> "}` command (since that's a PowerShell commandline).

Comment: is there a way to get it to save in the memory so i dont have to input the command each time?:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194339/how-to-permanently-change-powershell-and-cmd-prompts